# How to read a group of .csv files keeping just one specifc column from each one

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a bunch of .csv files that are similar (same number of rows and columns) in a folder. I want to read all of them in another dataframe keeping just one specific column (the 'Total' one) from each one (preferably with some header that identify the source file).
Here is what i have so far:

```
import pandas as pd
import glob
path = r'C:\Users\lsminervino\Desktop\MUN'
files = glob.glob(path + "/*.csv")
all_files = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(f , encoding="latin", sep=';', thousands='.', decimal=',') for f in files],axis =1, sort=False)
all_files.head()

OUT:

                  Unnamed: 0 Total  Cadastro  Sem Registro Civil  \
0        3500105 - Adamantina   0.0       0.0                 0.0   
1            3500204 - Adolfo   0.0       0.0                 0.0   
2             3500303 - Aguaí   0.0       0.0                 0.0   
3    3500402 - Águas da Prata   0.0       0.0                 0.0   
4  3500501 - Águas de Lindóia   0.0       0.0                 0.0   

                   Unnamed: 0 Total  Cadastro  Sem Registro Civil  \
0        3500105 - Adamantina   3.0       3.0                 0.0   
1            3500204 - Adolfo   0.0       0.0                 0.0   
2             3500303 - Aguaí   3.0       3.0                 0.0   
3    3500402 - Águas da Prata   0.0       0.0                 0.0   
4  3500501 - Águas de Lindóia   0.0       0.0                 0.0   

                   Unnamed: 0 Total     ...      Sem registro civil  \
0        3500105 - Adamantina   0.0     ...                     0.0   
1            3500204 - Adolfo   0.0     ...                     0.0   
2             3500303 - Aguaí   0.0     ...                     0.0   
3    3500402 - Águas da Prata   0.0     ...                     0.0   
4  3500501 - Águas de Lindóia   0.0     ...                     0.0   

                   Unnamed: 0 Total  Cadastro  Sem Registro Civil  \
0        3500105 - Adamantina   0.0       0.0                 0.0   
1            3500204 - Adolfo   0.0       0.0                 0.0   
2             3500303 - Aguaí   0.0       0.0                 0.0   
3    3500402 - Águas da Prata   0.0       0.0                 0.0   
4  3500501 - Águas de Lindóia   0.0       0.0                 0.0   

                   Unnamed: 0 Total  Cadastro  Sem Registro Civil  Unnamed: 4  
0        3500105 - Adamantina   0.0       0.0                 0.0         NaN  
1            3500204 - Adolfo   0.0       0.0                 0.0         NaN  
2             3500303 - Aguaí   0.0       0.0                 0.0         NaN  
3    3500402 - Águas da Prata   0.0       0.0                 0.0         NaN  
4  3500501 - Águas de Lindóia   0.0       0.0                 0.0         NaN  

[5 rows x 61 columns]
```

What i wanted is something like:

````
                   Unnamed: 0 Total_csv1  Total_csv2  Total_csv3  \
0        3500105 - Adamantina   3.0       3.0                 0.0   
1            3500204 - Adolfo   0.0       0.0                 0.0   
2             3500303 - Aguaí   3.0       3.0                 0.0   
3    3500402 - Águas da Prata   0.0       0.0                 0.0   
4  3500501 - Águas de Lindóia   0.0       0.0                 0.0  

```

Tks in advance
````

Comment: get rid of `axis=1` in `pd.concat`.

Comment: Have you considered using dask?

Comment: @QuangHoang it gave a df with a series of NAN

Comment: @rpanai Not really, but i think i would have the same problem with dask.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that everything goes down to the function with attach the file number to coulmn `Total`. Here is a full example:

```py
import os
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import glob

# Create dummy files
fldr = "data_test"
os.makedirs(fldr, exist_ok=True)
n_files = 10
N = 10
for i in range(n_files):
    df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(N,4),
                      columns=["Total", "a", "b", "c"])\
           .sample(int(N*0.8))\
           .to_csv(f"{fldr}/file_{i+1}.csv")

# list of files
files = sorted(glob.glob(f"{fldr}/*.csv"))
```

With the following function you want to

1. Extract file number `n` from filename.
2. Read the csv.
3. Set the index.
4. Rename the `Total` column using `n` from point 1.

```py
def customRead(fn):
    n = fn.split("/")[-1].split(".")[0].split("_")[-1]
    d = pd.read_csv(fn)[["Unnamed: 0", "Total"]]\
          .set_index("Unnamed: 0")\
          .rename(columns={"Total":f"Total_csv{n}"})
    return d
```

You can then concatenate the `df`s to obtain the desired output via

```py
df = [customRead(fn) for fn in files]
df = pd.concat(df, axis=1)
```

## Bonus Track

In case you have a lot of big files you can consider using `dask` as following

```py
import dask
df = [dask.delayed(customRead)(fn) for fn in files]
df = pd.concat(dask.compute(df, scheduler='processes')[0],
               axis=1)
```

Comment: Tks for the answer. It worked almost as i wanted. I did a mix with the answer from @Håkan Svensson and could make it work.
Here is the final code:
`def customRead(fn):
    n = 'Total_{}'.format(fn.rpartition('\\')[2]).replace(".csv", "")
    d = pd.read_csv(fn,encoding="latin", sep=';', thousands='.', decimal=',')[["Unnamed: 0", "Total"]]\
          .set_index("Unnamed: 0")\
          .rename(columns={"Total":f"{n}"})
    return d`

Comment: It makes sense as I created dummy `df`s. I suggest you to upvote @Håkan Svensson's answer too if this was helpful.

Answer (score 1):

```
all_files = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(f , encoding="latin", sep=';', thousands='.', decimal=',', usecols=['Total']).rename(columns={'Total':'Total_{}'.format(f.rpartition('\\')[2])}) for f in files], sort=False)
```

Edit: Windows path => changed to backslash in `rpartition`

Comment: This almost worked, but the final df didn't stored the results:
```  Total_Acampadas.csv  Total_Agricultores.csv  Total_Assentadas.csv  \
0                  0.0                     NaN                   NaN   
1                  0.0                     NaN                   NaN   
2                  0.0                     NaN                   NaN   
3                  0.0                     NaN                   NaN   
4                  0.0                     NaN                   NaN   ```

And it should gave me 644 rows and gave: [9681 rows x 15 columns]

Comment: In a further look i found that the resulting DF has a 644 rows with value in the first column. 644 NANs in the second column and after 644 values, and so on.
So its like the concat is putting the data below the other.